# RestRepositories Parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm playing with Java Spring and its Rest Repositories :)

Thus, let's get down to business.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "pigs", path = "pigs", excerptProjection = Pig.class)
@CrossOrigin
public interface PigRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Pig, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Pigs WHERE p.owner = ?#{principal}")
    Page<Pig> mine(Pageable p);

}
```

When searching for my pigs I want to filter by their status. Thus I've tried adding a param `@Param(value = "status") Status status`, and added to the query `and status like :status`.

Wunderbar! when I filter with status `/pigs/mine?status=BIG` I obtain my big pigs, but when no param is passed like in `/pigs/mine` I see no pigs.

Where are my pigs? :)

Comment: show us your Pig class.

Comment: Pig class is very yuge class. Btw status is `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, class is `@Entity` and Cloneable and have `@Id` et `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on a `private Long id`.

Comment: hard to tell based on the information, why don't you enable `show_sql` and see what happened there.